# Creating namespace alias for "base" requirejs config

Tags: requirejs, karma-runner, netsuite

So I am creating a test suite for my Netsuite scripts (Netsuite is a business management platform) and I am using the recommended frameworks Karmajs + Requirejs + jasmine to accomplish this objective.  When I run the tests, I am getting the following error:

```
08 07 2019 15:18:40.992:WARN [web-server]: 404: /SuiteScripts/CompanyNetsuite/Util/MathUtil.js
08 07 2019 15:18:40.993:DEBUG [phantomjs.launcher]: Error: Script error for "/SuiteScripts/CompanyNetsuite/Util/MathUtil", needed by: /base/Util/Calculator
```

This is due to the fact that "SuiteScripts/CompanyNetsuite" is a module namespace defined in Netsuite for the base directory of the scripts.  I have followed the advice of some StackOverflow entry and Requirejs map config documentation but it doesn't seem to work.

Below is an example of the directory structure. So in Netsuite, `Company-Suitescript` would be module `/SuiteScripts/CompanyNetsuite`:

```
Company-Suitescript
  |_ Util
   |_ MathUtil.js
  |_ Calculator
   |_ PointsCalculator.js
 .
 .
 .
```

In Invoice/script1.js, for instance, it has:

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NModuleScope Public
 */
define([
        '/SuiteScripts/CompanyNetsuite/Util/MathUtil'
    ], function(MathUtil){...}
```

So to handle that in testing, I have written the following in test-main.js file:

```
require.config({
    baseurl:"../../",
    paths: {
        N: 'base/tests/unit/mocks/N'
    },
    map: {
        "SuiteScripts/CompanyNetsuite/Util" : {
            "MathUtil" : "Util/MathUtil.js"
        }
    }
});
```

I have also tried:

```
require.config({
    baseurl:"../../",
    paths: {
        N: 'base/tests/unit/mocks/N'
    },
    map: {
        "SuiteScripts/CompanyNetsuite/Util" : {
            "MathUtil" : "base/Util/MathUtil.js"
        }
    }
});
```

Package.json info version:

```
{
...
"devDependencies": {
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "requirejs": "^2.3.6"
  }
}
```

I am expecting `SuiteScripts/CompanyNetsuite/Util/MathUtil.js` to the specified `base/Util/MathUtil.js` script. I am pretty sure I am missing something.  Assistance would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, everyone who took a moment of their time to view my issue.

After deep dive debugging, I found the solution.  As stated before, I missed something:

1. The `/` before SuiteScripts.  I seem to have assumed that either this was appended by default or was equivalent `/SuiteScripts/CompanyNetsuite/Util/MathUtil` to`SuiteScripts/CompanyNetsuite/Util/MathUtil.`
2. I needed to remove
   the `base` from `base/Util/MathUtil`.  The resulting compilation was
   `../../base/Util/MathUtil`, which is incorrect.  The `base` is a directory defined by KarmaJS during compilation.

So the resulting config:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '/base',
    paths: {
        N: 'tests/unit/mocks/N'
    },
    map: {
        "*" : {
            "/SuiteScripts/CompanyNetsuite/Util" : "Util"
        }
    }
});
```